Seaborn heatmap with extra row and extra column
I made a seaborn heatmap and I would like to add an extra row and column like image. They must be independent, I will fill each one with its own data.

I made one through 'quick fix', adding extra row and column in dataframe, and then plotting white vertical and horizontal lines.
Is there a 'correct' way to do this? Some feature for this porpouse?

Please share some code.

Your situation is rather specific: no labeling for the rows nor columns, a shared coloring, no color bars. Each of those would need space, which isn't obvious. Thicker lines have the drawback of cells having different sizes and loosing their symmetry. Certainly, there isn't a feature that tackles your very specific situation. A mainstream approach would be subplots with unequal sizes
